# Returning error after applying SelectPercentile

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I got an error telling me my data contain np.nan, np.inf or values too large for float64

I was doing automatic feature selection. The features were too much so I want to streamline it down.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.